# Rename all columns of dataframe by extracting pattern in column name

Tags: r, rename

I have a dataframe about stock-market data and I want to delete a specific pattern from all column names. This is my dataframe:

```
           ADS.DE.Open ADS.DE.High ADS.DE.Low ADS.DE.Close ADS.DE.Volume ADS.DE.Adjusted
2017-01-02      149.75      151.95     149.35       151.30        445138        143.6014
2017-01-03      150.90      151.05     148.80       149.25        641172        141.6557
2017-01-04      149.40      149.40     146.35       146.40        618563        138.9507
2017-01-05      145.25      145.80     143.50       144.30        739147        136.9576
2017-01-06      143.80      145.05     142.95       144.80        641054        137.4322
```

And now I want to remove the `"ADS.DE"` pattern from all colums. So that I get the fllowing output:

```
                  open        high        low        close        volume        adjusted
2017-01-02      149.75      151.95     149.35       151.30        445138        143.6014
2017-01-03      150.90      151.05     148.80       149.25        641172        141.6557
2017-01-04      149.40      149.40     146.35       146.40        618563        138.9507
2017-01-05      145.25      145.80     143.50       144.30        739147        136.9576
2017-01-06      143.80      145.05     142.95       144.80        641054        137.4322
```

I already have a solution that works:

`ADS.DE %>%
rename_(.dots=setNames(names(.), tolower(gsub(str_c("ADS.DE","."), "", names(.)))))`

But my problem is that I have a lot of dataframes with the same structure and the same problem. I now intend to put my working solution into a map-function. The problem will be the part marked in bold:

`ADS.DE %>%
rename_(.dots=setNames(names(.), tolower(gsub(str_c(`**"ADS.DE"**`,"."), "", names(.)))))`

My main concern is tho put my solution into a map-function.
Similar to the following:

`DAX<-c("ADS.DE","MRK.DE","DB1.DE","EOAN.DE","SAP.DE","BEI.DE","FME.DE","WDI.DE","BMW.DE","HEN3.DE","VOW3.DE","LIN.DE","DBK.DE","FRE.DE","MUV2.DE","DTE.DE","BAYN.DE","RWE.DE","SIE.DE","VNA.DE","ALV.DE","IFX.DE","1COV.DE","DAI.DE","BAS.DE","LHA.DE","CON.DE","HEI.DE","DPW.DE","TKA.DE")`

`map(mget(DAX),
    function(x) x %>% rename_(.dots=setNames(names(.), tolower(gsub(str_c(substitute(x),"."), "", names(.))))))`

Can someone help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Does the string you're trying to get rid of always match the name of the `data.frame`?

Comment: @BenjaminYe Yes the string always match the name of the dataframe

Comment: @GKi The problem is that I have 30 dataframes with different names. `ADS.DE` is only an example

Comment: You can just use `sub('.*\\.', '', names(df))`. No need to specify anything

Comment: The quantmod package lets you refer to `Op(ADS.DE)`, `Lo(ADS.DE)`, `Hi(AD.DE)`, `Cl(ADS.DE)` and `Vo(ADS.DE)` so maybe you don't need to change the names.

Comment: @Sotos Yes that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution:

`map(mget(DAX),function(x)
  x%>%rename_all(str_remove , ".+\\..+\\.")%>%rename_all(tolower)
)`

Answer (score 1):

`rename_()` is deprecated and I wouldn't use `rename()` either. `set_names()` works better.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_table("
           ADS.DE.Open ADS.DE.High ADS.DE.Low ADS.DE.Close ADS.DE.Volume ADS.DE.Adjusted
2017-01-02      149.75      151.95     149.35       151.30        445138        143.6014
2017-01-03      150.90      151.05     148.80       149.25        641172        141.6557
2017-01-04      149.40      149.40     146.35       146.40        618563        138.9507
2017-01-05      145.25      145.80     143.50       144.30        739147        136.9576
2017-01-06      143.80      145.05     142.95       144.80        641054        137.4322")

df %>%
  set_names(names(.) %>% str_remove(".+\\..+\\."))
```

Answer (score 1):

try with str_replace from stringr on the names() of the dataframe

```
library(stringr)
names(df)<-str_replace(names(df), "ADS.DE", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will apply changes to a list of data frames and solve your problem:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ABS.DE.x = "a", ABS.DE.y = "b")
df2 <- data.frame(ABS.DE.x = "c", ABS.DE.y = "d")

fix_names <- function(list_df){
lapply(list_df, function(df){
  setNames(df, stringr::str_replace(names(df), ".+\\..+\\.", ""))
})
}

a <- fix_names(list(df1, df2))

a[[1]]
```